# Navegação não ocupando tamanho total do browser

Tags: html, nav-bar, css

é o seguinte, reparei agora num erro que o meu site tem, é o seguinte, eu defini o max-width da pagina para 1366px, se eu fizer zoom out no browser todos os elementos ocupam a largura total do browser. Mas acontece que a minha navbar, com width 100%, so vai até aos 1366px, nao era suposto ocupar a largura do ecra total assim como os outros items?

Outro erro é que quando faço zoom-in e zoom-out o logo na navbar nao acompanha a navbar, simplesmente aumenta o tamanho ou diminui desproporcionalmente à navbar.

HTML:

```
<nav>
        <div class="row">    
            <img class="logo" src="img/logo.png" alt="logo">
          <ul class="menu menu-js">
            <li><a href="#about_us"><i class="ion-ios-search-strong icon-small clearfix"></i>SEARCH</a></li>
            <li><a href="#search"><i class="ion-ios-people icon-small clearfix"></i>TOP ARTISTS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#top_artists"><i class="ion-ios-person icon-small clearfix"></i>ABOUT US</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contacts"><i class="ion-ios-telephone icon-small clearfix"></i>CONTACTS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contacts"><i class="ion-ios-unlocked icon-small clearfix"></i>SETTINGS</a><ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="#">LOGIN</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">REGISTER</a></li>
                </ul>
                </li>
          </ul> 
        </div>
        </nav>
```

CSS:

```
.menu,
.menu > li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.menu {
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    /* impede que os menus quebrem */
    text-align: center;
}

.logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0.6%;
    transform: translateY(-5%);
    float:  left;
    width: 14%;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: 5%;
}

.menu {
    text-align: right;
    padding: 0;
}

.menu > li {
    background-color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 14%;
    text-align: center;
}

.menu > li:last-child {
    margin-right: 5%;
}

.menu>li>a {
    font-size: 75%;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 15px 0;
    color: #74C8D2;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.menu>li>a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #74C8D2;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.menu>li>a::after,
.menu>li>a::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5px;
    content: "";
    opacity: 0;
}

.menu>li>a::after {
    top: 100%;
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(50% -50%, ellipse, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 80%);
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at 50% -50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 80%);
}

.menu>li>a::before {
    top: -5px;
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(50% 150%, ellipse, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 80%);
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at 50% 150%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 80%);
}

.menu>li>a:hover::after,
.menu>ul>li>a:hover::before {
    opacity: 1;
}

.menu>li>a>i {
    vertical-align: middle;
}



/* submenu */

.sub-menu {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    background: #fff;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

.menu li:hover .sub-menu {
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 1;
}


.sub-menu li {
    display: block;
    font-size: 75%;
    text-align: center;
}

.sub-menu li a {
    padding: 10px 30px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #74C8D2;
}

.sub-menu li a:hover,
.sub-menu .current-item a {
    background: #74C8D2;
    color: #fff;
    transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...eu defini o max-width da pagina para 1366px, se eu fizer zoom out
>   no browser todos os elementos ocupam a largura total do browser. Mas
>   acontece que a minha navbar, com width 100%, so vai até aos 1366px,
>   nao era suposto ocupar a largura do ecra total assim como os outros
>   items?

Quando você define um `max-width`, não importa o *zoom out* que fizer, o tamanho não irá ultrapassar o que foi definido. Os elementos internos da `div` irão crescer, mas as `div` em si não irá ficar mais larga do que foi definido.

> Outro erro é que quando faço zoom-in e zoom-out o logo na navbar nao
>   acompanha a navbar, simplesmente aumenta o tamanho ou diminui
>   desproporcionalmente à navbar.

Você definiu um tamanho em porcentagem `%` na *logo*, com isso, mesmo dando zoom na página, a *logo* não irá acompanhar porque seu tamanho é fixo em porcentagem baseada nas dimensões do *viewport*, então sempre será 14% da tela, mesmo com zoom in ou out. Se você colocar um tamanho em pixels `px`, por exemplo, aí sim, irá crescer ou diminuir com o zoom.

No exemplo abaixo a imagem de exemplo na *logo* está em pixels. Faça um zoom e veja que ela acompanha o tamanho do zoom:

```css
.menu,
.menu > li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.menu {
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    /* impede que os menus quebrem */
    text-align: center;
}

.logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0.6%;
    transform: translateY(-5%);
    float:  left;
    width: 100px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: 5%;
}

.menu {
    text-align: right;
    padding: 0;
}

.menu > li {
    background-color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 14%;
    text-align: center;
}

.menu > li:last-child {
    margin-right: 5%;
}

.menu>li>a {
    font-size: 75%;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 15px 0;
    color: #74C8D2;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.menu>li>a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #74C8D2;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.menu>li>a::after,
.menu>li>a::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5px;
    content: "";
    opacity: 0;
}

.menu>li>a::after {
    top: 100%;
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(50% -50%, ellipse, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 80%);
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at 50% -50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 80%);
}

.menu>li>a::before {
    top: -5px;
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(50% 150%, ellipse, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 80%);
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at 50% 150%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 80%);
}

.menu>li>a:hover::after,
.menu>ul>li>a:hover::before {
    opacity: 1;
}

.menu>li>a>i {
    vertical-align: middle;
}



/* submenu */

.sub-menu {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    background: #fff;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

.menu li:hover .sub-menu {
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 1;
}


.sub-menu li {
    display: block;
    font-size: 75%;
    text-align: center;
}

.sub-menu li a {
    padding: 10px 30px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #74C8D2;
}

.sub-menu li a:hover,
.sub-menu .current-item a {
    background: #74C8D2;
    color: #fff;
    transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<nav>
        <div class="row">    
            <img class="logo" src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg" alt="logo">
          <ul class="menu menu-js">
            <li><a href="#about_us"><i class="ion-ios-search-strong icon-small clearfix"></i>SEARCH</a></li>
            <li><a href="#search"><i class="ion-ios-people icon-small clearfix"></i>TOP ARTISTS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#top_artists"><i class="ion-ios-person icon-small clearfix"></i>ABOUT US</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contacts"><i class="ion-ios-telephone icon-small clearfix"></i>CONTACTS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contacts"><i class="ion-ios-unlocked icon-small clearfix"></i>SETTINGS</a><ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="#">LOGIN</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">REGISTER</a></li>
                </ul>
                </li>
          </ul> 
        </div>
        </nav>
```

Comment: Obrigado amigo! Ajudou muito!